# atmel studio start new project page is empty

Tags: visual-studio-2015, atmel, atmelstudio

I just installed atmel studio 7 and I can't make a new project, i even tried to use an example project, but the it gives the error

> project creation failed

Here's what I get whenever I try to make a new project

[image]

I dunno if that is relevant or not, but I have VisualStudio 2015 installed before any of this.
Also, I think Atmel studio 7 comes with it's own compiler, so there is no need to install WinAVR.

**What should i do ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution to this mess, my guess is that Atmel studio 7 installs visual studio shell that conflicts with the visual studio 2015 that is already installed, so what i did is :

> 1. uninstall Atmel studio 7
> 2. uninstall visual studio
> 3. restart PC
> 4. install Atmel studio
> 5. install visual studio(be careful, see note in edit)

sometimes you might find it hard to do step 2, if you can't then try to restore windows using a restore point before installing Atmel. and then try to do it again.

---

EDIT: Just wanted to add that if VS and AS are both installed, no matter what is the order of installation, VS will always work just fine, and AS won't work.

Comment: This was also a step in the right direction for me as well. Although I had to remove all versions of my Visual Studio Installations (VS2012 Professional, VS2013 Community, VS2015 Community)